# How to prevent clicking on dates and display alert message in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

So my code is as below:

```
var date = new Date();
var active_dates = [<?php 
                $i=0;   
                for($i=0;$i<=count($booked_dates);$i++) {
                    echo "'".$booked_dates[$i]."',";
                }
            ?>];
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
    $('#single_datepicker_1').datepicker({
        rtl: KTUtil.isRTL(),
        todayHighlight: true,
        templates: arrows,
        startDate: date, //disable all old dates
        setDate: date, //tomorrow's date allowed
        multidate: true,
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

         beforeShowDay: function(date){
                 var d = date;
                 var curr_date = d.getDate();
                 var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                 var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                 var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year

                 if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
                   return {
                      classes: 'bookedDates'
                   };
                 }
              return;
          }
        //maxDate: '28/12/2019'

    });
```

Now the code which prevent booked dates clickable and display alert message:

```
    $('.bookedDates').click(function(event) {
    console.log('Preventing');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    alert("fdf");
});
```

Now, based on above code my datepicker looks like below:

[image]

However, the issue is when I go to the next month like, April then the alert message is not displaying and the reason is, April month is not initially loaded on datepicker. As current month is March.

So if you click on any below dates alert message won't be display:

[image]

can anyone please let me know what I should do so that the alert message will display if I click on April month dates.
Thanks:)

Comment: You need to grey out future dates?

Comment: nope, I am more looking into display alert message box

Answer (score 0):

The library provides a way to disable some dates. Simply pass this as part of your options.

`datesDisabled: [date_sttings],`

Or you can pass a single date string. Note the date strings must follow the date format you already defined.

Alternatively you can have an array of disabled dates. And when users select a date. You first check to see if its in the array of disabled dates. If it is, you then show the alert and perform other actions as you please.

Comment: sorry for delay reply as was trying other solution too. Well, I'll give it a go to one of your solution "check if the selected dates in an disabled dates array". I am not 100% looking for this check as that I can do it as well but anyways thanks for your answer. Will look into it.